automatic conversion to custom type with pydantic's validate_call
Is there a way to tell pydantic that conversions to an "arbitrary" types are fine?
from astropy.time import TimeDelta
from pydantic import validate_call

@validate_call(config=dict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True,strict=False))
def f(dt: TimeDelta): ...

dt = TimeDelta('15s') # OK
f(dt) # OK
f('15s') # error

Obviously I checked the doc, but could not find a documented way to do this.
